# how to have fixed 2 digits in EditText with, with input starting from after decimal point?

Tags: android

Say the user types the the numbers inside an EditText with input type decimal;

```
524
```

the edit text should format the value as `5.24`

and if the user has typed just one digit so far

```
5
```

edit text should have the value `0.05`

Im trying to use TextWatcher, but im having trouble understanding how it works.

Comment: Do you want the user to just input numbers?

Comment: what is so hard about it? you are just deviding 100 to watever number typed in edittext. do the calculation and set it to edittext back.

Comment: @Jolson it'll keep dividing the number? i type 5, it outputs 0.05, i type 4 next, and it'll devide 0.054 by 100

Comment: Oh thats complicated. it will go into loop. u know i tried it. as i set the result value back to edittext. it calls again onTextChange. infinite loop